# Pass Parameters to a API Controller from Workflow HttpSend Control

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-activity

I need to make a api call from my workflow(Method type is POST), I am using HttpSend control from Microsoft.Activities to do this. I am able to call my api but not able to send parameters from workflow to api. I tried passing a simple string type parameter through RequestContent in HttpSend but still not able to retrieve its value in my api call.

Screen Shots

Can you provide me a simple example or a link to explain how can i pass parameters from workflow to api for POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe the RequestContent parameter of Call HTTP Web Service action for setting payloads to submit to the service.
See this similar example from SHarePoint
https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/08/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-service-from-sharepoint-designer/